# How to fix "class UUID cannot be cast to class String"

Tags: mongo-java-driver

I'm storing a UUID in Mongo DB and when I want to read it again from MongoDB with

```
UUID.fromString(document.getString("userId"))
```

I get:

```
class java.util.UUID cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.util.UUID and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.UUID cannot be cast to class java.lang.String
```

But the `Document` class of the Java Mongo Driver has no `.getUUID()` method.
How to fix this?

I was expecting to be able to read the UUID without errors.

Answer (score 0):

The fix seems to be:

```
(UUID)document.get("userId")
```